# How to make a jquery sortable item draggable only after the item is clicked?

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable menu works fine, but I also have a click event on every sortable item, now if drag and sort the menu the click event get fired at same time ,what I want is the sortable item can only be draged after I click it, kind of like only active item can be dragged.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you elaborate  more? perhaps show some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable dragging after the click event was fired:

```
$('#target').click(function() {
  $('#target').draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

Cancel drag unless the given element is the 'selected' one:

```
(function() {
  var selectedTarget = null;
  $('.target').draggable({ drag: function(event, ui) { 
    if(this != selectedTarget) return false; 
  });
  $('.target').click(function() { selectedTarget = this; });
});
```

Delay drag start slightly (enough time for the click event to propagate):

```
(function() {
  $( ".target" ).draggable({ delay: 500 });
});
```

Both these work on the basis that all your sortable objects have the `target` class